# clear/create file on script start, append otherwise

Tags: python

I am appending lines to a file using `open` mode:

```
Chimera=open("file.txt","a")
```

I do this in a loop.

I would like the file to be cleared if the script is re-run, instead of appending to a file created by a previous run. How can I do that?

here is an exemple

```
liste=["A","B","C"]

file= open("file.txt","a")
for i in liste:
   print(i, file= file)
```

so I get the file.txt such as :

```
A
B
C
```

but if I run the same script again I get:

```
A
B
C
A
B
C
```

instead of just

```
A
B
C
```

Comment: Edited to clear a bit the language and question - if you do not approve you can revert the edit.

Comment: I suggest you add your loop so we see why you need appending.

Comment: thanks, I edited to be more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just open the file for *writing* and not *appending*. You can write multiple times to the same file object, "appending" content to the resulting file, even in *write* mode.

The difference is that write mode (`"w"`) will start with an empty file each time, whereas append mode (`"a"`) will append to *whatever file already exists*.

Basically, just do:

```
liste = ["A","B","C"]

with open("file.txt", "w") as liste_file:
    for i in liste:
        print(i, file=liste_file)
```